# Table block variation with header section activated

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I am attempting to create a default table variation with the header section toggled on. There is no boolean attribute to activate the header section it seems and instead it’s an array.

I was able to add the header section with the below code but it then doesn’t activate the ‘create table wizard'(where user chooses amount of columns/rows before table is generated) and it also breaks the “insert row” function unless I also add the attribute body": [{"cells": [...

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation('core/table', {
        name: 'my-table',
        title: 'Table',
        attributes: {
            className: 'is-style-regular',
            head: [
                {
                  cells: [
                    {
                      tag: "th"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
        },
        isDefault: true,
    });
```

If block variation can’t toggle the header section without losing the wizard and insert row functionality then is there another way of doing it?